# How to deploy spring boot app project to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, spring-boot

I have created a simple server that uses JPA repository and returns a response in Json. It includes methods post and get. It is a spring starter boot app project and everything works on my localhost (I use postman to send and receive json objects). My problem is when I try to deploy to Heroku I run into many problems. I added a jetty-runner dependency and plugin. I also created a procfile as shown below:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Initially the target folder was empty and `foreman start web` was saying that it `couldn't find my war file`, so I added the following line to pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

But the project created an error, so I disabled maven nature of the project, then configured maven again and then it included pom.properties and pom.xml in the target folder. When I tried to deploy it, it said it was unable to access jetty jar file in target/dependency because there was no folder like that. So I did `maven install` and it installed the missing folders. Now I get the error that `No transaction manager can be found`, so I installed a dependency for jetty-plus and Atomikos. But now I still get the error that there is not transaction manager found and there is a java.net.bindexception.

I feel like I am really on the wrong path. I was wondering if anyone can tell me from the beginning on how to deploy a spring starter boot project to heroku. Any help would really be appreciated.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Challenge-Server1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                      <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
                        <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                      </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you're in a maze of problems. Why don't you take a step back and generate a plain webapp via http://start.spring.io (with jar packaging selected) and try deploy that? Spring Boot documentation even includes how the Procfile should look like. When you get that to work you can copy over other bits of your original application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that the deploying a spring boot application is a little different then deploying spring boot mvc project. Basically you don't need a jetty-runner dependency or plugin, you just do the following steps:

- Configure a mvn project
- mvn clean and install
- Declare Procfile as: web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar

All found from this site:
http://web.archive.org/web/20171018145733/http://nicholaspaulsmith.com/spring-boot-on-heroku/

Answer (score 1):

I outlined some details in my blog

https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2016/11/04/spring-boot-heroku-example/

The main point is to use the heroku maven plugin like this

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
mvn clean install
# Creates an app with the specified name, without setting up a git remote
heroku create <APP-NAME> --no-remote

#deploys the jar file
heroku deploy:jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --app <APP-NAME>
```

but there are more details like how to set up a CI/CD pipeline